# Seleccionar una clase con sus hijos con JS

Tags: javascript, css3

Alguien podría decirme como puedo guardar en una sola variable lo siguiente:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <a href="">22</a>
    <a href=""></a>
</nav>

<nav class="nav">
    <a href="">22</a>
    <a href="">x</a>
</nav>
```

Guardar todos los `nav` y `div` en una variable y que cuando tenga algo en el segundo `div` cambie el estilo de su padre `nav`.

Esto es lo que llevo de momento. He conseguido que lea y que lo cambie pero solo del primer `.nav` que detecté... La cosa seria cambiar de estilos el padre `nav` si detecta que el segundo `div` tiene algún contenido.

```
let atrib = document.querySelector('.nav a:nth-of-type(2)').hasChildNodes() === true;
let menu = document.querySelector(".nav");

if (atrib) {
  menu.classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas en una variable, tendrás que jugar con lo que te devuelve para hacer esa condicion y darle la clase, tal como lo haces ahora, en la variable estas seleccionando el primer nav.

$(".nav")

[Selectors](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-selectors-selectores-4768/)

Answer (score 0):

No ibas mal encaminado. Yo lo haría de esta manera:

Si quieres capturar todos los `.nav` necesitas usar `querySelectorAll()` en vez de `querySelector()`. Una vez obtenida una colección con todos los elementos `.nav` podemos iterarla a través de la función `forEach()`.

Luego, por cada iteración capturamos el segundo hijo para comprobar si tiene o no contenido y en caso de tenerlo pues le añadimos la clase `active` al menú que estamos iterando en ese momento.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let menus = document.querySelectorAll(".nav");

  menus.forEach(function (menu) {
    let enlace = menu.children[1];
    let tiene_contenido = enlace.hasChildNodes();

    if (tiene_contenido) {
      menu.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
};
```

```css
.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
 <a href="">22</a>
 <a href=""></a>
</nav>

<nav class="nav">
 <a href="">22</a>
 <a href="">x</a>
</nav>
```